# Ruby - generate sha512 hash of a string

Tags: ruby

Is this a correct way to generate Sha512 of a string in ruby?

`hashed_s = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest s`

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: You may also need to `require 'digest'` at the top of the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to covert a string to a SHA512 hash in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412285/how-to-covert-a-string-to-a-sha512-hash-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You may need to `require 'digest'` at the top of the file, too, as this isn't part of the ruby *core* library:

```
require 'digest'

s = "My awesome string"
hashed_s = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest s
```